# How to mock an async function returning a tuple?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I need to test the following function

```
class C:
    async def f():
        a, b = await self.g()  # need to mock g
```

However, the following test got the error of `TypeError: object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression`

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_f():
    sut = C()
    sut.g = MagicMock(return_value=(1,2)) # TypeError: object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression
    await sut.f()
    sut.g.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AsyncMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock) instead of the `MagicMock`:

```
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_f():
    sut = C()
    sut.g = AsyncMock(return_value=(1,2))
    await sut.f()
    sut.g.assert_called_once()
```

`AsyncMock` is part of the standard library since Python 3.8; if you need a backport for older versions, install and use the [`asyncmock`](https://pypi.org/project/asyncmock/) package.